# WebKit events and raw events of ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[Advanced User Interactions API](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Native_events_versus_synthetic_events) says that Chrome Driver supports two types of events: *WebKit* and *Raw*:

> ChromeDriver provides two modes of supporting native events called WebKit events and raw events. In the WebKit events the ChromeDriver calls the WebKit functions which trigger Javascript events, in the raw events mode operating systems events are used.

**Question:** How to switch between them? What is the default?

I'm asking because I found that the default way works fine with PPAPI Flash (built into Chrome), but unfortunately doesn't work with NPAPI Flash:

```
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(Testee, x, y).Click().Perform();
```

I'm forced to use NPAPI Flash because I have to check trace logs (flashlog.txt).

Comment: I was also looking for an answer to this question. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. However I resolved my root issue and now I'm able to test flash.